# How to add more than one menu item in Visual Studio 2012 using VSPackage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sdk

I studied this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to add custom menu command using VSPackage in Visual Studio 2012.

Everything is fine until when I want to add more than menu item.

In provided documentation, they didn't explained how to add one more menu item.

For instance, I made the following setting in `TfsUtility.vsct` file:

```
<Menus>
    <Menu guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="TfsUtility" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />
        <Strings>
            <ButtonText>Tfs Utility</ButtonText>
            <CommandName>Tfs Utility</CommandName>
        </Strings>
    </Menu>
</Menus>
```

...

```
<Group guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="TfsUtility"/>
</Group>
```

...

```
<Button guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
    <Strings>
        <ButtonText>Branch</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
</Button>
```

...

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" value="{d5549d5d-47af-40e0-a7e5-e9ed7f64d577}">

    <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
    <IDSymbol name="cmdidMyCommand" value="0x0100" />

    <IDSymbol name="TfsUtility" value="0x1021"/>
</GuidSymbol>
```

Questions:

1. How to add more option in menu option (After Branch for example)  ?
   [image]
2. How to associate command for each menu item ? I want to display different messages for each menu item.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. In `PkgCmdIDList` page, add some constants like:

   ```
   public const uint cmdiChangesets = 0x101; // or cmdiYourMenu instead of cmdiChangesets
   public const uint cmdidCheckin = 0x102;
   public const uint cmdidGet = 0x103;
   ```
2. Create callbacks (in YourProjectNamePackage, for me is TfsUtilityPackage) for click events like

   ```
   private void TfsMenuItemBranchCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // do something
   }

   private void TfsMenuItemPendingCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // do something
   }

   ...
   ```
3. In XXUtility.vsct (for me TfsUtility.vsct), create buttons in `<Buttons>` node

   ```
           <Button guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="cmdidChangesets" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
               <Parent guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
               <Strings>
                   <ButtonText>Changesets</ButtonText>
               </Strings>
           </Button>

           <Button guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="cmdidCheckin" priority="0x0102" type="Button">
               <Parent guid="guidTfsUtilityCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
               <Strings>
                   <ButtonText>Pending changes</ButtonText>
               </Strings>
           </Button>
   ```
4. Add IDSymbol in `<GuidSymbol>` node

   `<IDSymbol name="cmdidChangesets" value="0x0101" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidCheckin" value="0x0102" />`

The value `0x0101` must match with value of constants from `PkgCmdIDList` class which is `0x101` and the value must be different in order to display all menu items

Answer (score 4):

1. To add one more menu item, add one more Button section with a different id.
2. To implement a command you need to provide your MenuItemCallback and register it with OleMenuCommandService:

> OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
>
> ```
> if ( null != mcs )
> {
>    // Create the command for the menu item.
>    CommandID menuCommandID = new CommandID(guidCommandGroup, myCommandID);
>    MenuCommand menuItem = new MenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID );
>    mcs.AddCommand( menuItem );
> }
> ```

See [Command Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.